# Excel Macro to auto hide rows when date is enter in specific column cell

Tags: excel, vba, hide, rows

I am new to VBA and am still learning. What I am trying to accomplish seemed easy enough but am having difficulty. I need to write a macro that auto hides a row when a date (any date) is entered into the cell of a specific column.

E.g. data is recorded in columns A:F. When a "shipped" date is entered into G2, row 2 auto hides.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

McJ

Comment: Can you please add a code example?

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA code will hide the associated row if a cell in column 'G' is edited and changed to a date (number) between zero and the current date:

```
Option Explicit

Private lastSelectedCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Set lastSelectedCell = Range("A1")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' If the most recently selected cell was in column 6 ('G')
    If (lastSelectedCell.Column = 6) Then
        ' If the previously selected cell was a date on or before today
        If ((lastSelectedCell.Value <= Date) And (lastSelectedCell.Value > 0)) Then
            ' Hide the entire row
            Rows(lastSelectedCell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
    Set lastSelectedCell = Target
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respone. However it isn't working. Says:     "If (lastSelectedCell.Column = 6) Then" =<object variable or with block variable not set> Again I am new at this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MCJ The `Worksheet_Activate()` method needs to run to initialise the `lastSelectedCell` variable. Try saving and re-opening the `.xlsm` file and the error should disappear.